# Blood Pressure Representation of Blood Pressure like Withings ? How to Obtain using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I have a line chart with 2 series where we can represent data with two different lines for Blood Pressure. Something like one mentioned below:-
[image]

On the other hand I am required to change the graph to something like the one mentioned below. This is somewhere my ideas dont work. I am not able to understand how to have two points and join them as they belong to two different series. The chart mentioned below is to be made using Highcharts.

[image]

Help me to understand what type of graph can be used for such situation.

Comment: You possibly have 2 arrays (1 for systolic and 1 for diastolic) values. I imagine that it would be a matter of manipulating these array to what the HighCharts input requires.

Comment: Do you have any solution before giving a negative point. Please let me know.

Comment: @jeff pretty correct. What I want to ask is which type of chart or what kind of configuration is required. I have tried multiple stuff but am not able to understand.

Comment: I wasn't being negative. Without any data or structure or code to work on it is virtually impossible to give you any meaningful answer.

Comment: @jeff thanks a lot jeff. To explain me the situation. I figured out that renderer could help me to achieve the same. :)

Comment: @jeff i will close it miself ;P

Answer (score 2):

How about using scatter series with lineWidth and null points between them? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ssdg6nug/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter'
    },
    series: [{
      lineWidth: 1,
      data: [
        [0, 1],
        [0, 9],
        [0, null],
        [1, 13],
        [1, 9],
        [1, null],
        [2, 14],
        [2, 22],
        [2, null],
        [3, 11],
        [3, 21],
        [3, null],
      ]
    }]
});
```